# How to restore/load a DB saved state in Datatables?

Tags: datatables

I am using stateSaveCallback to save a Datatables state into the database. It submits the current state via AJAX to a script so I can save the JSON.

I can attach the save function to a button click like so:

```
$( ".save_state" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    table.state.save();
});
```

But I cannot find any documentation on how to restore or load that script using a click. The closest reference I can find is on this page 
https://datatables.net/reference/api/state.loaded() which references restoring the saved state.

I am using stateLoadCallback but I think this just does it on load. I would like to do it via a click, so users can save their state in the database and click restore to load it back later (we will offer multiple state saves, like a Saved Search, so they click to restore a saved search).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the source code, it looks like state loading is performed only once during initialization. Therefore your best bet is to use [`destroy`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy) option as `destroy: true` and re-initialize your data table on click.

I assume you have defined a callback using [`stateLoadCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateLoadCallback) option that query the server upon re-initialization.